# Glossary in SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010

I am a Business Analyst working on a SharePoint Team site for our IT group. For a project I'm working on for our group, I'm trying to setup a "glossary of terms" in a SharePoint. I started this general glossary in a word doc, but would like to move it to SharePoint. The word doc supports cross reference hyperlinking, and section hyperlinks A, B, C...
What are my best options for a non-code option not using a paid solution? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Something as simple as a wiki page would allow you to author content like this. That said, the better (perhaps more useful) approach might be to create each entry of the glossary as a list entry. You could then give people filterable, categorized, or different sorted views of the same information. There's no code ways to do that (create lists, perhaps have a calculated column that gets the first letter of the entry so you can filter by A, B, C, etc. You could also do additional customization (light code) to further enhance how that's rendered and used, but you wouldn't *have* to do that.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a wiki or use HTML pages. The list approach that Mike mentions is another good alternative.

You could also look into using it as a term set as part of managed metadata depending on what you need to do with the glossary.